# why String and wrapper classes work well as keys in hashtables?

Tags: java, oop, hashtable

why it's prefered to use Strings and wrapper that represents a specific object in hash tables rather than using the actual object itself?

Comment: by `actual object`, are you referring to primitives such as `int` and `double`?

Comment: Please clarify. `String` is not a wrapper object for anything. What wrappers are you referring to? If you mean wrapper types (`Integer`, `Boolean`, etc.) for primitive types, it's because primitive types cannot be type parameters.

Comment: are you talking about autoboxing?

Comment: can you elaborate a bit on this question?  because Id say its better to just use the object, however as Jon pointed out you cant use primatives therefore you have to use wrappers in certain instances.

Comment: This was a terribly incomplete and vague question that was lucky to get a good answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is a bit vague, but maybe this helps:

- The key must be immutable. String (Integer, Long) fits this nicely. (Of course this does not help if you later change the object to no longer match the key).
- The key must implement the hashCode/equals contract. String (Integer, Long) already does this.
- You can lookup by key without having to create an instance of your custom object.

So, if you are keying on a property or computed value for a custom object, it is convenient (and safe) to use a "primitive" built-in class to represent that derived value.

In fact, it is rarely necessary or advisable to use a custom class for hashtable *keys*, you can cover almost everything with Strings, Integers and Longs (frequent exception: tuples, for which Java has no good built-in class, and arrays don't work as hash keys).